# Access Google Analytics without original login credentials

Tags: google-analytics, authentication, password

Our Google Analytics administrator has forgotten the login credentials for our account. How can we recover this?

Comment: I think that this is the question for web aplications SE.

Answer (score 1):

**To reclaim a Google Analytics account after the administrator has left / forgotten credentials:**

1. Find out your Google Analytics ID (You can find this by looking at your page source code, it will look like UA-xxxxxxxx-x)
2. Sign into, or sign up for, Google Adwords
3. Head to the Google Adwords Help center, you'll see a 'Contact Us' button - click this
4. Choose the 'Email' option
5. Choose 'Google Analytics' in the next screen
6. Then Choose 'Analytics Administrator has left'
7. Fill in the form and wait for someone to contact you